# Proving the divergence of an integral

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I want to prove the divergence/convergence of $\int_1^\infty \cfrac{1}{x^p}dx$

So when I take the integral $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^t \cfrac{1}{x^p}dx$$
I get $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\biggr[{\cfrac{x^{1-p}}{1-p}\Biggr\vert_{1}^{t}\ }\biggr], p\ne 1 \\ $$

And so I see that when $p<1$ then the argument of the limit is nonnegative. So as $t$ grows then the limit approaches $\infty$ since $t^{1-p}>1-p$. But I don't know what to make of the limit when $p>1$ because my limit produces $-\cfrac{1^{1+p}}{1+p}$
This suggests the integral converges for $p>1$ but that doesn't sound right to me because $1/x^p$ is very similar to $1/x$, which I know certainly diverges.

Comment: The argument of the limit is $\frac{t^{1-p}}{1-p}-\frac1{1-p}$ and it is always non-negative for $t\ge1$ by the simple fact of being $\int_1^t x^{-p}\,dx$. I don't undersand your argument of $x^{1-p}>1-p$ and the limit diverging to $\infty$ as $x\to \infty$. For one thing, because the variable is $t$; secondly and most importantly, because $1-p$ is a constant.

Comment: Yes $1-p$ is constant but I'm trying to be careful to not overlook what constants do to my integral. When p>1 that makes $1-p<0$, so then I'd have to take the reciprocal of $x^{1-p}$. I know that's still positive, but I'm trying to see where my variable moves to (denominator or numerator) so I have an idea whether or not the limit approaches 0 or infinity or something like that

Answer (score 1):

$\frac 1  {x^{p}}$ is not similar to $\frac 1 x$. It tends to $0$ faster than $\frac  1 x$ as $x \to \infty$. The integral of $\frac 1 x$ diverges but the integral of $\frac  1{x^{p}}$ converges and the value of the integral is $\frac  1{p-1}$.